# Concrete example of Symfony's Create own framework, custom error handling

Tags: symfony

https://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/http_kernel_httpkernel_class.html

I would be needing a better example of this tutorial since i'm getting php uncaught errors after following the tutorial.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class '*controller name*' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Controller\ControllerResolver.php on line 133

So it's not launching my ErrorController even i'm registering subscriber like so:

```
$listener = new HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener(
            'Controller\ErrorController::exceptionAction'
        );
        $dispatcher->addSubscriber($listener);
```

Other subscribers are working for me:

```
$dispatcher->addSubscriber(new HttpKernel\EventListener
\RouterListener($matcher, $requestStack));
$dispatcher->addSubscriber(new HttpKernel\EventListener
\ResponseListener('UTF-8'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors says that php cannot find class `Controller\ErrorController`, check its path, namespace and class name.

Comment: nono, i just wrote 'controller name' for an example. the real path and controller are not errorcontroller related. I have the path in routes.php and controller::action assigned to it.

Comment: It doesn't matter, Symfony just cannot find and instantiate controller's class.

Comment: but why isn't the error related to my custom error controller? i'm getting the php uncaught error. It should be caught error right? returning my own 'not found', 404 error response msg.

Comment: That's right, it looks like the error handler cannot instantiante error controller.

Comment: it's working now, i forgot to add $routes->add('error', new Route('/error', array('_controller' => 'Controller\\ErrorController::exceptionAction'))); to my routes.php file. Documentation never mentioned it.